# Android flip image animation

Tags: android, animation

I want to flip image in android through translate animation.

eg:- suppose i have one card. when translate animation starts it shows the card into the new position. now here the card should flip? from backside to front.
how can i do that.?

Comment: what about considering use of [ViewSwitcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html)?

Answer (score 18):

The name of the example in APIdemos is :
**Rotate3dAnimation.java**

Just check the below given link also. It can give you a good idea in solving your problem.
[android-animations-3d-flip](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html)

Thanks,
Sen

Comment: This answer works fine, I also used this example. @vivek: You should accept if it if worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the API demos, there is an example given there. It's really great!

Comment: Nobody is here who can give me answer of my question?

Comment: The APIDemos example can be found Views --> Animation --> 3D Transition. Implementation seems to be in com.example.android.apis.animation.Transition3d.java and com.example.android.apis.animation.Rotate3dAnimation.java