# Fllip Animation between two activity

Tags: android, animation, flip

hello I know probably this is repeat question but please help me

I want to flip animation between two activity

I have to separate activity and i want to flip animation if i call second activity using **StartActivity(Intent)**

Comment: There should already be an animation between activities, do you want to change the default?

Comment: I want to use flip animation like I-Phone

Comment: Hey @Dr. Jackal, see this post: http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android flip image animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335199/android-flip-image-animation)