# How to provide flip animation when calling another activity in android

Tags: android, flip

I want to load activity with flip animation. I have already seen api demos and haven't clarified that how to do this.So guys please suggest me.
Thanks

Comment: Can you be more explicit?
And have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335199/android-flip-image-animation)?

Comment: Thanks David but this is not working in case of activity ,See i have flip activity.I hope is clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For adding the flip animation When loading an activity.First you should add animation to the resource "anim" folder.the animation should be of flipping in and out.the in your java file after calling an intent you should add this piece of code.

```
(this).overridePendingTransition(R.anim.incoming, R.anim.outgoing);
```

This will help you to Solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks Sree Dev But,When we use this code activity comes right-to-left but we have to rotate this..So please give me some idea..

Comment: Ya the animation can be changed by providing the correct xml to the anim folder.You will get rotation animation xml.just use it with this code I think it will work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853997/android-rotate-animation-between-two-activity  this piece of code will help you.

Comment: Thanks Sree Dev,See I don't have to rotate activity only have to flip it when we call another activity.. So please tell me this regard..

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is correct, but you'll still need transitional xml files. I posted full snippets on my blog so check it there - [Flip between two Activities](http://quodev.wordpress.com/2013/12/21/flip-between-two-activities/)

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain a effective and very easy to implement effect with these xml files.

**rotate_out.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<scale
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="0.0"
    android:toYScale="0.90" />

<alpha
    android:duration="1"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:startOffset="500"
    android:toAlpha="0.0" />
```

**rotate_in.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<scale
    android:duration="200"
    android:fromXScale="0.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.90"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:startOffset="500"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0" />

<alpha
    android:duration="1"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:startOffset="500"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />
```

Then in your code override transition after startActivity() or finish():

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.rotate_in, R.anim.rotate_out);
```