# How to flip an image in Xamarin Android?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, xamarin, xamarin-studio, flip, poker

I'm creating Poker game. So initially I'm showing back face of playing cards and then I need to add flip animation on the cards to show the value of cards. I've searched the net but I didn't find anything that could have helped me.
my code is as follows.

```
void LoadBacksideOfCards()
    {
        player1Card1.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.backside);
        player1Card2.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.backside);
        player2Card1.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.backside);
        player2Card2.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.backside);
        player3Card1.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.backside);
        player3Card2.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.backside);
        player4Card1.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.backside);
        player4Card2.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.backside);

        centerCard1.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.backside);
        centerCard2.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.backside);
        centerCard3.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.backside);
        centerCard4.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.backside);
        centerCard5.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.backside);
    }
```

And showing the cards using following code

```
void ShowCenterCardNumber(int cardNumber)
    {
        if (cardNumber == 3)
        {
            centerCard4.SetImageResource(DrawableImageMap[_shuffledCardsData.CenterCardsData[3].CardNumber + _shuffledCardsData.CenterCardsData[3].CardType]);
        }
        else
        {
            centerCard5.SetImageResource(DrawableImageMap[_shuffledCardsData.CenterCardsData[4].CardNumber + _shuffledCardsData.CenterCardsData[4].CardType]);   
        }

    }
    void ShowFirstThreeCenterCards()
    {
        centerCard1.SetImageResource(DrawableImageMap[_shuffledCardsData.CenterCardsData[0].CardNumber + _shuffledCardsData.CenterCardsData[0].CardType]);
        centerCard2.SetImageResource(DrawableImageMap[_shuffledCardsData.CenterCardsData[1].CardNumber + _shuffledCardsData.CenterCardsData[1].CardType]);
        centerCard3.SetImageResource(DrawableImageMap[_shuffledCardsData.CenterCardsData[2].CardNumber + _shuffledCardsData.CenterCardsData[2].CardType]);
    }
```

I want to add some flip functionality to make it more interactive to users.
I'm using simple XML (without MONO Games).
any help in this regard will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few suggestions:
http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html
http://2cupsoftech.wordpress.com/2012/09/18/3d-flip-between-two-view-or-viewgroup-on-android/
[Android flip image animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335199/android-flip-image-animation)
https://github.com/castorflex/FlipImageView